# How can I check if my string starts with <p> and add that text if it doesn't in C#

Tags: c#

If I have string named codeText. Sometimes that string starts with a `<p>` and other times not. Can anyone tell me how I can check if it starts with `<p>` and if it doesn't then how can I add the `<p>` to the start and `</p>` to the end.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
if (!text.StartsWith("<p>", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    text = "<p>" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(text) + "</p>";
```

If you somehow know that the HTML string does not contain any malicious Javascript, you don't want to call `HtmlEncode`.

Comment: What does HtmlEncode do for me? I do have a problem if there's an apostrophy in the text or if there are back or forward arrows. Will HtmlEncode help?

Comment: Can I do this with the ? operator?

Comment: Yes; ​​​​​​​yes.  `HtmlEncode` escapes HTML characters so that the text is treated as plain text.  You probably want to call it in all circumstances.

Answer (score 5):

```
if(!text.StartsWith("<p>"))
{
    text = string.Format("<p>{0}</p>", text);
}
```

Comment: Can I do this with the ? operator?

Answer (score 3):

You mean like this?

```
if (!codeText.StartsWith("<p>"))
{
    codeText = string.Concat("<p>", codeText, "</p>");
}
```